# Xcode 10.1 single view playground template displays as empty black view

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I'm trying to use a Swift playground to prototype some simple drawing code. Starting with the single view iOS template:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Nothing controversial there. I'd expect it to include everything required to get the string "Hello World!" on screen (otherwise, why is it in the template?), but if I run it all I see is a black rectangle.

After noticing that applying a `UIAnimation` is enough to cause the view to render correctly, I've experimented and found the minimum change to the template to make it actually draw something is:

```
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
let vc = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
vc.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Is my setup misbehaving or is the shipped template inadequate to produce visible output?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  This seems like a video card issue.  One of machines has the same issue (except your fix doesn't even fix it) and the other with exact same code works fine.  What kind of hardware and OS version are you running?

Comment: It was an i5 Air running High Sierra that caused me to write the original post. Trying it again now, the default template doesn't render anything or complete (the 'play' button changes to 'stop' and never reverts, and there's a perpetual spinner next to "Running MyPlayground"). My "fix" isn't making a difference either. A `print()` statement added to `loadView()` doesn't get executed either, so I'm not sure it's a video card problem. An un-modified template on a 2017 5k iMac works fine.

Comment: try adding extra setNeedsDisplay() and start with a clean template.  At some point mine rendered before it stopped again.  The consensus seems to be that playground is buggggy.  I really like the idea of it though.